# Is it misleading to list the awarding body of a qualification, rather than the school where I earned it?

Tags: resume

In my CV, I have a TESOL qualification which is administered by Trinity College, London - which is a reputable institution. The School of English where I took the TESOL qualification isn't exactly famous. In the education section of my CV, I have my TESOL qualification listed as my most recent education - as I did it after my Bachelors - and the name of the institution is the school where I took the qualification.

Could it potentially be misleading to an employer, if I changed the institution on my CV to Trinity College, given as I have an official certificate from them, and they are the central body which awards the qualification?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Could it potentially be misleading to an employer, if I changed the institution on my CV to Trinity College, given as I have an official certificate from them, and they are the central body which awards the qualification?

It wouldn't be "potentially" misleading.. it would be out and out misleading. Or in common parlance - a **lie**. Don't do it.

Anyone who knows enough about TESOL to be looking for it on a CV will know that the providers for the course get certified by Trinity College in order to offer it so they aren't going to give a monkeys' about which one you went to.

If you're applying for something more general - i.e. they aren't looking for TESOL specifically then you're just name dropping it because the institution is prestigious. And it's a lie - and one that you're going to end up looking pretty silly for.